# How to find character after pipe "|" in C#

Tags: c#

I would like to find character after `|` and check in a loop in C#.

Like I have `Test|T1`. After pipe the character could be anything like `Test|T2` or `Test|T3`.

The first value is `Table|Y` and second value could be `Test|T1`, `Test|T2` or `Test|T3`.

So I would like to check the character after `|` in else block.

```
  foreach (var testing in TestQuestion.Split(','))
  {
       if(testing.Equals("Table|Y"))
            {
        order.OrderProperties.Add(new OrderProperty("A")
        {
          ...
        });
        }

     else
          {
        //check the value after "|"
      }
                        
    

 }
```

So I would like to check the character after `|` in else block.

Comment: `string.Split('|')`?

Comment: @stuartd, If I split the string like `string.Split('|')` then I am only getting `Test`. I would need character after `|` like `T1`, `T2` or `T3`.

Comment: you need string.IndexOf and String.Substring

Answer (score 3, accepted):

like this

```
var s = "XXX|T1234";
var idx = s.IndexOf("|");
if (idx > -1) // found
{
     var nextChar = s.Substring(idx + 1, 1);
}
```

if its possible that '|' is the last character then you need to check for that

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this,

```
var tokens = test.Split('|');

if (tokens.FirstOrDefault() == "Test" && tokens.LastOrDefault() == "T1")
{

}
```

Comment: no need to split to find this

Comment: yea, sure, but just for the fun of thinking about new ways. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way (to test if value is T1 for example):

```
if (testing.Split('|')[0] == "Test" && testing.Split('|')[1] == "T1")
{
    
}
```

Comment: Splitting twice is a waste of resources.